# How would I keep my rest api cookie between my windows forms? c# api rest

Tags: c#, api

I have a dilemma to create an api, in c# aspnet net framework and another project in windows form net framework, create a login form and it is that when I log in the login form of my Windows Forms application, the user authenticates me from the api that I am getting a message that I am successfully logging in, but after I am redirected to my Windows Forms application's login form (view where I display the data in a user control ), it tells me access denied (send unsuccessful error ), in Postman it works fine for me because the browser saves the auth cookie it generates in the login controller but in the forms it's like it doesn't send the cookie and that's why I get access denied error
and I don't know how to solve it [I clarify that I am new]

```
**# controller login in mi api web not mvc**
```

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Login(UserRegistre user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                UserRegistre userOK = db.UserRegistre.Where(x => x.UserR == user.UserR && x.Password == user.Password).FirstOrDefault();

                if (userOK != null)
                {

                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userOK.UserR, false);
                    return Ok("Estas iniciando sesion espere...");
                  
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest("Algo salio mal usuario o contraseña incorrecto, o puede que este registro no exista en la base de datos");


                }
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Erro en el proceso de solicitud");
            }
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult close()
        {
            FormsAuthenticatiÑÑon.SignOut();
            return Ok("cerrando");
        }
```

```
Controller Notes
```

```
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Note> Select()
        {

           
            Model1 db = new Model1();
            return db.Note.ToList();
          
       

        }
 

        [HttpPost]
   
        public IHttpActionResult Insert(Note e)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                Model1 db = new Model1();
                db.Note.Add(e);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return Ok("Nota Agregada.");

            }
            else
            {

                return BadRequest("error algo salio mal ");

            }
        }

        [HttpPut]
      
        public IHttpActionResult Update(Note e)
        {


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Model1 db = new Model1();

                db.Entry(e).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Ok("Nota Editada Sastifactoriamente.");

            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Error  en el Proceso de actualiaion.");
            }
        }

        [HttpDelete]
      
        public IHttpActionResult Delete(Note e)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Model1 db = new Model1();
                db.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                db.SaveChanges();

                return Ok("Nota Eliminada");


            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Error en el Proceso Solicitado");

            }
        }
```

```
# **this in the windows forms Home**
NOTE: I am loading the data in a user control list, not in a datagrid.
```

```
        private string url = "https://localhost:44386/";

        private string api = "/api/Notes";
        public int matricula;



# metod show items  Note: Unrealization error because you don't have access to the controller Notes****your text**
```

```
    public void mostrarItem()
    {
        try
        { 
            var cliente = new RestClient(url);
            var request = new RestRequest(api, Method.Get);
            var response = cliente.Execute(request);
         

            List<ENotasForm> listestu = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ENotasForm>>(response.Content);

            UserControl1[] ListaNotas = new UserControl1[listestu.Count];

            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < ListaNotas.Length; i++)
            {


                ListaNotas[i] = new UserControl1();
                ListaNotas[i].Title = listestu[i].Title;
                ListaNotas[i].Code = listestu[i].Code.ToString();
                ListaNotas[i].Content = listestu[i].Content;
                ListaNotas[i].Datetime = listestu[i].Date_Time.Value.ToString();
                ListaNotas[i].FormInicio = this;


                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(ListaNotas[i]);



            }


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hay un error en la solicitud");

            return; 
        }
       

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a **[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)** of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please also check [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: How are you returning the login cookie from the login form back to main code?  To return a value from the windows form you have to keep the form open when you return from the form.  See my two form project. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: in the login form it only returns the message that you are logged in, when the login form is hidden
You already lose the cookie data from the login form